# npx create-react-app doesn't work anymore after I installed yarn (even after uninstalling yarn)

Tags: npm, create-react-app, yarnpkg, npx

Everything was working perfect, I even had it going earlier. All I am trying to do is create a react app. I used the command npx create-react-app and everything worked.

I decided to try yarn instead of npm, that made everything not work. After bashing my head against the wall I decided to uninstall it and I get the exact same error as when I had yarn installed.

It's giving me this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtWka.png) warning that I am using npm version 5.1.0 EVEN THOUGH you can see at the bottom that I have version 8.11.0. On top of that I get "npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function" I tried googling it on Stack Overflow. The guy says to uninstall node_modules but I am pretty sure I already have it removed.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a configuration error in your node/npm PATH, in most situations a reinstall is the quickest way to fix your problem: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/the-best-way-to-reinstall-node-js-mac-linux-windows-d5f3212fdd2e

Comment: I figured it out..... I just had to do this rm -rf node_modules

Answer (score 0):

You need to uninstall the `create-react-app` module with either npm or yarn with `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` then run the create react-app command again to install latest version.

See more about this on the official site [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/)